# Getting the row and column numbers that meets multiple conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to get the `row` and `column` number, which meets three conditions in Pandas DataFrame.

I have a DataFrame of `0`, `1`, `-1` (bigger than `1850`); when I try to get the `row` and `column` it takes forever to get the output.

The following is an example I have been trying to use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, size=(1845,1850)))

b = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, size=(5,1850)))
b[b == 1] = -1

c = pd.concat([a,b], ignore_index=True)

column_positive = []
row_positive = []

column_negative = []
row_negative = []

column_zero = []
row_zero = []

for column in range(0, c.shape[0]):
    for row in range(0, c.shape[1]):
        if c.iloc[column, row] == 1:
            column_positive.append(column)
            row_positive.append(row)
        elif c.iloc[column, row] == -1:
            column_negative.append(column)
            row_negative.append(row)
        else:
            column_zero.append(column)
            row_zero.append(row)
```

I did some web searching and found that `np.where()` does something like this, but I have no idea how to do it.

Could anyone tell a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) would be one way to do it. Here's an implementation with it -

```
# Extract  the values from c into an array for ease in further processing
c_arr = c.values

# Use np.where to get row and column indices corresponding to three comparisons
column_zero, row_zero = np.where(c_arr==0)
column_negative, row_negative = np.where(c_arr==-1)
column_positive, row_positive = np.where(c_arr==1)
```

If you don't mind having rows and columns as a `Nx2` shaped array, you could do it in a bit more concise manner, like so -

```
neg_idx, zero_idx, pos_idx = [np.argwhere(c_arr == item) for item in [-1,0,1]]
```

Comment: Thanks, @Divakar. I also think you can edit the answer with `np.column_stack(np.where(c.values == 1))`.

Comment: @akshay Or simply : `np.argwhere(c_arr == 1)`, etc. That's what the second approach with `np.argwhere` tries to achieve.

Comment: True, my bad. Thanks anyway.